# What do you call people who like word puzzles?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for, or the name for, a person who enjoys solving word puzzles, crosswords, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

[Cruciverbalist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cruciverbalist):

> - A person who enjoys or is skilled at solving crosswords. (ODO)
> - An enthusiast of word games, especially of crosswords. ([AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cruciverbalist))
> - A crossword puzzle enthusiast. (Collins)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cruciverbalist&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccruciverbalist%3B%2Cc0): *cruciverbalist*, the term is relatively recent, its usage is from '80s.

Comment: doesn't include other word puzzles

Comment: It does, according to AHD definition.

Comment: Cruci - cross; verb - word.  I'd suggest that the American Heritage Dictionary's definition is too broad in its meaning.

Comment: wow!  who knew??!

Comment: @Grizzled: AHD often is more broad. Josh61: Can you find it in any other dictionary defined as not limited to crosswords?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - I posted 3 definitions from sources which are considered reliable by our site standards. As you mentioned AHD gives a broader definition, and for good reasons in my opinions. World puzzles are generally part of crosswords magazines, and crosswords are generally the most common and known kind of word puzzles. With that respect the definition may well cover a wider range of puzzles as suggested by AHD.