# What do you call someone who solves puzzles?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, slang

What is a term or name for someone who is very adept at solving puzzles or situations that require though processing and logic.

I ran across [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251022/what-do-you-call-people-who-like-word-puzzles), however this only deals with crossword puzzles. I'm looking for something that could be applied on a broader sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Enigmatologist*** is the word for the person you describe. The term was coined by Will Shortz, the former editor of *Games* magazine, which I read voraciously as a child. He's currently the editor of the *New York Times* crossword puzzle. Mr. Shortz is apparently the only person in the history of the world to have a degree in Enigmatology (the University of Indiana, 1974).

Comment: And specifically, one who solves, or has any connection to crossword puzzles is a cruciverbalist.

Answer (score 2):

A [puzzler](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puzzler) can either be a puzzle or somebody who solves puzzles.

Answer (score 0):

One who is [analytical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/analytical?s=t) would be a good problem solver. And in this context might presumably be more apt to solving puzzles then others.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com)

skilled in or habitually using analysis.

Answer (score 0):

***[Solutionist](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/solutionist)*** has a wider meaning and may refer to someone who solves problem in a more general sense:

> - a problem-solver (Collins)

***[Solutionism](http://www.yourdictionary.com/solutionism)***:

> - The belief that all difficulties have benign solutions, often of a technocratic nature.

(Yourdictionary.com)

Comment: In the Oxford Dictionary On-Line, *solutionist* is not given any entry at all. It is also underlined in red by my Internet-Explorer spell-checker. But *solver* is there in the dictionary and accepted by Microsoft, at least. I would call such a person a *problem-solver*.

Comment: @WS2 - the term is present also in M-W, it is not a common one but still it is used. - *" a very good listener and solutionist for whatever our needs were.*" https://books.google.it/books?id=BqNRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22solutionist%22&dq=%22solutionist%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMupqT_fTKAhXhF5oKHdS_B-YQ6AEITjAI

Comment: In my area of work (computer software) "solutioneering" is a term of mild derision meaning to suggest solutions to a problem without first fully understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a term or name for someone who is very adept at solving puzzles or situations that require though processing and logic?**
I'm looking for something that could be applied on a broader sense.

Normally I do not comment on other answers but, however novel the word **Enigmatologist** is. It is not included in many dictionaries and is **not an approved word** in those it does appear in. Also it does not answer the question, only part of it.

The word that can be applied in a broader sense is **problem-solver** It is rather mundane but it does cross the t's as well as dot the i's

> **problem-solving**; noun; [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/problem-solving?q=solver); the process of finding solutions to problems:
>
> **problem-solver**; noun; [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/problem-solving?q=solver)
>
> example; He is considered a troubleshooter and a problem-solver.